# How to remove html tags from database text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I remove html elements in a text field from SQL Server?

Comment: Do you mean removing html tags from a text field or from a blob/clob field?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean removing html tags from a field stored in a database. If so, and if you can code the solution in .NET, I would have used the [HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to traverse the html contents, and save the InnerText (i think that's the property name) of the elements in which you are interested to a variable. Then replace the contents of the field with the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CLR Procedure (SQL Server 2005 and above) to decode the HTML , stripping out the tags.

This looks like an example of what you want to achieve.

[SQL Server CLR Procedure](http://www.sqlclr.net/Examples/tabid/55/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/31/Default.aspx)